# How to find the number of males between the age

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame is below

*Find the number of males that is greater than 40  less than 60

*Find the number of Females that is greater than 40  less than 60

```
customer_Id DOB Gender
0   268408  02-01-1920  M
1   268408  02-01-1950  M
2   268408  02-01-1990  F
3   268408  02-01-1970  M
4   268408  02-01-1950  F
```

** First create column DOB to age, then df.age > 40 & df.age < 60

Pseudo code

now = pd.Timestamp('now')
only_date, only_time = now.date(), now.time()

`df['age'] = (pd.to_datetime(only_date) - df['DOB']).astype('<m8[Y]')`

info > `DOB 207518 non-null datetime64[ns]`
its not substracting

Expected out

```
M 1
F 0
```

Comment: I don't understand anything you wrote here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby('Gender').DOB.agg(lambda grp: np.count_nonzero(
    (pd.Timestamp.today() - grp).astype('timedelta64[Y]').between(40,60)))
```

*pd.Timestamp.today() - grp* is the age of the current person.

*astype('timedelta64[Y]')* converts it to years.

*between(40,60)* returns a *bool* - whether the current person is
in the required age range.

And finally *np.count_nonzero(...)* counts *True* values.

The whole above computation is performed for both genders.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to respect the calendar year if you want to get age perfectly correct. This can be accomplished with `pd.offsets.DateOffset`. First we convert DOB to a `datetime`, then we can check if the DOB occured between today - 60 years and today - 40 years.

```
import pandas as pd

df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DOB)

today = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()
m = df.DOB.between(today - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=60), 
                   today - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=40),
                   inclusive=False)

# Subset and Count
df.loc[m].Gender.value_counts()
#M    1
#Name: Gender, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Or feel free to switch to the `lt`, `le`, `gt`, `ge` operators if you want to differentially include/exclude the lower bounds. I'd test the edge cases because explicitly to make sure you get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime as dt

def cal_age(dob=str):
    x = dt.datetime.strptime(dob, "%d-%m-%Y")
    y = dt.date.today()
    age = y.year - x.year - ((y.month, x.day) < (y.month, x.day))
    return age


df['Age'] = df.DOB.apply(lambda z: cal_age(z))

df[df.Gender=='M'][df.Age < 60][df.Age > 40].count() # male
df[df.Gender=='F'][df.Age < 60][df.Age > 40].count() # male
```